# Gear Problems, cassette shifting

Tags: gears

I was tuning my gears on my road bike and I left it when it shifted up and down every gear well but now the next day it is very odd, when clicking the lever it now sounds different and it now won't go to the biggest sprocket on the casstte and then when I go to change down it jumps all of the gears back to the smallest sporcket.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the ratchet is broken. Please show a picture of the gear shifter or describe its type

Answer (score 1):

I guess that when indexing your gears, one of the ferrules wasn't seated in the frame housing properly.   Or possibly the outer came loose from the shifter, giving the same effect.

This would leave up to ~10mm of extra slack in the inner cable, preventing you from getting to the big cogs.

The fast-change to hard gears I can't explain, would suggest checking that the rear mech hanger is not bent and the cage/rear derailleur is vertical.

---

Noted that three weeks ago you changed rear mech in [Derailleur Hanger Replacement](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81197/derailleur-hanger-replacement) .  It is likely something's not right there, so please post some photos and we'll see it directly.